# Who is Kouu the tyrant king?

Tags: reincarnation-no-kaben

I'm reading the manga "Reincarnation no Kaben": there, the main characters get some powers from their previous lives, and hence are named after famous people of history.

I managed to find all of them except who the main antagonist should be: he is named after "Kouu the tyrant king". Does someone knows who the historical character they are referring to is? (Or is it a made up character?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is a mistranslation. 
According to this site: http://tyuumokuneta.net/post-1718-1718 the original name in the manga is [項羽 / Xiang Yu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Yu), an ancient chinese warlord.

Comment: Note that the Japanese pronunciation of the name 項羽 is こうう _kouu_. (I agree that this is a mistranslation; in English, the name should be rendered in romanized Chinese.)