# Why did the storm dragon's name change from Verudora to Veldora in the anime?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In the first episode of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime*, we are introduced to a storm dragon named "Verudora" ([episode 1](https://www.crunchyroll.com/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-as-a-slime/episode-1-the-storm-dragon-veldora-777519), time code 16:38 at Crunchyroll). From episode 2 onward, the dragon's name was altered to "Veldora". The show's English [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Time_I_Got_Reincarnated_as_a_Slime) shows his/her name in Japanese as "(ヴェルドラ Verudora)". So why did the production company start with one pronunciation and immediately switch to another on the next episode? I remember that some reviewers on YouTube had problems pronouncing the dragon's name for that first episode, but it's really not that hard, just four short syllables, each ending with a vowel.

(Note that I went ahead and asked my question, knowing that the episode 1 sub script has already been altered in the last few weeks to use "Veldora", just like all the other episodes.)

Comment: my guess would be that the first translation, "Verudora", was chosen because it matches the romaji, and was changed to "Veldora" to match the pronunciation more closely (when read with an average english accent)

Comment: Related? [Why do Japanese names change within a manga to have various forms at different times?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/39722)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The japanese writing system doesn't have a symbol for just the `l` sound. The closest they have are the symbols in the `r` column in the kana table. The `u` row is most often used when the vowel is silent. So you end up with ru: ル. Which means that if you ask someone to write Veldora in katakana they would effectively write Verudora.

However when translating to a latin alphabet and you only have the katakana to base yourself on you must try and divine what the author wanted with the name. Official translators can ask the author though sometimes there is a delay with the reply. So the translators have to go with *something* until they got the official answer back.